# Windows domain account, expired vs. disabled status

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, resources, expired

I know that expiration feature in a Windows domain environment for user accounts is useful for automation processes. But I'd like to know if a disabled account is the same than an expired account in terms of accesibility to the domain.

In the other words, if I had to avoid the access to the domain resources for a user account, disabling and expiring have the same effect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are effectively the same.  The only difference is the message displayed to the user when they attempt to logon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They don't differ on the resulting effects, but on the *motivations* (read: why?) of the deactivation. See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/682c1b80-ae6b-45c4-9d0f-cf80b75f6264/account-expired-and-account-disabled-what-is-the-difference?forum=winserverDS) for more details.